# Regular Expression to unmatch a particular string

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am trying to use regular expression in Jmeter where in I need to unmatch a particular string. Here is my input test string : <activationCode>insvn</activationCode>

I need to extract the code insvn from it. I tried using the expression :
[^/<activationCode>]\w+, but does not yield the required code. I am a newbie to regular expression and i need help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use look-behind assertion in jmeter? If so, you can use thatr regex which will give you a word that follows `<activationCode>`

```
(?<=\<activationCode\>)\w+
```

If your input string is encoded (e.g for HTML), use:

```
(?<=\&lt;activationCode\&gt;)\w+
```

Comment: Actually the input test string is somewhat odd like this : &lt;activationCode&gt;ybwg1f&lt;/activationCode&gt;  from which i need to get that code.. when i typed it in the question field it converted itself to a html tag

Comment: thanks szymon.. it helped a lot.. i need to explore regex extensively.. i just started to use it yesterday.. do u wish to refer me to some bookd or sites which are good at regex for a beginner and then move onto complex ones?? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There's plenty of resources but I'm afraid I don't know any particular one that's good for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

When designing a regular expression in any language for something like this you can match your input string as three groups: (the opening tag, the content, and the closing tag) then select the content from the second group.